# CDate function error in IIS 6.0, Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, .net

We are running .NET 2.0 ASMX web services on Windows 2003 server on IIS 6.0. We have migrated a legacy VB 6.0 application to .NET 2.0 application using VB.NET. CDATE function is used at many places and we did not replace that with .NET equivalent date functions.

*After migration, code was working fine for many years.*

*Recently,* we have started encountering issues on our production servers where the below code fails:

CDATE("11 Jul 2011 21:10:27")

Error: Conversion from string "11 Jul 2011 21:10:27" to type 'Date' is not valid.

*If we perform an iisreset, the same code starts working fine.*

Could this be due to some recent patch for Windows server/ .NET patch?
Please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: How long after a reset before it starts to fail again? A particular time of day, perhaps?

Comment: And this is a bit pedantic, but in VB.Net, CDate() is no longer defined as a function. It is now an _operator_.

Answer (score 1):

General advice: Don't use IISReset. Recycle only the application pool with the problem.

This won't fix the issue but will cause less downtime when restoring service.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I suspect that it works for SOME dates and not for others.

In order to recognize and process a date, the CDate function derives the ideal date format from the systems locale settings. Check the regional settings on the server and make sure that your input format matches a system date format.

Ideally, fix this programmatically, by getting a datetime format from the IFormatProvider interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx

Comment: See also SetVarConversionLocaleSetting if it seems to change when someone logs on/off to the server. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306044 (and related links) - think this still applies today. Programmatic solution is best; pragmatic solution may win anyway :)